# What sources of damage are not caused by players?

Tags: bang

In the character list, it's states in *El Gringo* description that

> Note that *Dynamite* damages are not caused by any player.

So my question is: there are other cards which damage is not caused by any player?

### *Gatling* and *Indians!*

In [*BANG!* FAQ](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang/bang_faq_eng.pdf) it's stated that *Gatling* and *Indians!* are caused by the player who played them.

> **Q05. Who is considered to be responsible of the elimination of a player with cards like *Indians!* and *Gatling*?**
>
> A. Unlike the Dynamite, the player who played the *Gatling* or the *Indians!* is  considered to  be responsible of the elimination of a player. All special actions due to this elimination apply to him (for example, if he just killed an Outlaw this way, he draws the 3 cards reward).

Comment: not sure your question is exactly a repeat of this but This previous question covered the syntax of 'damaged are not caused by any other player' https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/character-specials-triggering-on-non-bang-cards/2625#2625

Comment: As a general rule that would be any card that does not cause damage when it is played by the cards but based on some other action such as revealing the top card of the deck.

Comment: @StartPlayer So the answer is that there is no card beside _Dinamite_ that do damage not caused by any player?

Comment: I think that there are a few cards in expansions that can also cause damage but I am not sure which is why I didn't answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a player plays a card  that instantly deals damage to one of more players, that damage is considered caused by a player. This includes all possible brown cards with a 'bang' symbol.

If the damage is delayed (as it is with dynamite), it is not caused by any player. This is probably partially because it is impractical to keep track of who played it (especially when there are multiple dynamites going around).

That being said, dynamite is the only card in the base game that has this property. Off the top of my head, the card 'Rattlesnake' in the Valley of Shadows expansion is the only other card I know of that has similar behavior.

[image]